# Send custom iOS native errors with sentry-expo

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, expo, sentry

I want to capture the iOS native errors to Sentry and also capture some custom messages.

I'm using the sentry-expo library but this only captures javascript errors even with the parameter:

```
 deactivateStacktraceMerging: false
```

I'v been following the official installation guide [https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/](http://sentry-react-native) but I'm stuck when trying to configure the AppDelegate.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ExpoKit.h"
#import "EXViewController.h"
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
#if __has_include(<React/RNSentry.h>)
#import <React/RNSentry.h> // This is used for versions of react >= 0.40
#else
#import "RNSentry.h" // This is used for versions of react < 0.40
#endif
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) EXViewController *rootViewController;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(EventsObserver*)getEventsObserver
{
    return EventsObserver.shared;

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    _window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[ExpoKit sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    _rootViewController = [ExpoKit sharedInstance].rootViewController;
    _window.rootViewController = _rootViewController;

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self getEventsObserver];
    [RNSentry installWithRootView:rootView];

    return YES;
}
```

At this point I don't have the rootView object of type RCTRootView. I'm using a EXViewController and the library does not support that type of object to invoke the function **installWithRootView**.  Am I following a wrong path?